# Soldering XLR Cables together

Tags: soldering, balanced, xlr

I'm aware that the structure of a balanced cable is an integral part of maintaining signal quality.

If I was to solder two XLR cables together in an effort to make one longer XLR lead, what would be the potential consequences? Would the it lead to a degradation of the signal because of an interrupt to the shield and twisting of the pairs? Is there any difference to just plugging two XLR leads together?

Comment: Technically, there would be an impedance discontinuity compared to just having one continuous cable. But just plugging two connectors together also makes an impedance discontinuity unless the connectors were specifically designed to not do that. I don't know if XLR connectors are. Whether or not the impedance mismatch is enough to actually matter is another matter.

If the cable is a twisted pair doing that will mess that up a bit. That's probably more important than the impedance mismatch.

Comment: If you're in the middle of the jungle then it could be a solution. But you will spend less time to solder a new one. And even if it works, you'll get some nasty thing.

Comment: XLR connectors are normally use for 600 ohm audio over STP cables up to 200 feet long. Splicing is tricky, as the turns-per-inch should be maintained. The shield should be put back together with no gaps in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the things one usually uses XLR for (Low impedance audio balanced lines, sometimes RS485 (DMX) and sometimes small DC power, it will likely be absolutely no issue, all this stuff is fairly robust, and it is not like anyone ever claimed that an XLR was a controlled impedance connector (Or suitable for any frequency where one would care).

On a theoretical level you have an impedance discontinuity and a break in the shield, but I can usually find something actually important to worry about.

Unless you are doing something weird, it will be fine, but for neatness I would normally fit a male/female connector pair and then just plug them together, in a mad scramble however, tape and twisting will generally work in a pinch.